# want to see WhatsApp chat msg from old number

Tags: applications

My old number is recycled and now I have my whatsapp back up with that old number in my google account. how to catch up with old msg with that one group that still exists and just one person.

Please help.. I am in such a dilemma as I asked the mobile provider company. But they already recycled my old number and now it is in use with some other person.
Thank you

Comment: "how to catch up with old msg with that one group that still exists and just one person." Can you explain this line in more detail?

Comment: Yes.. I made a group, whose I was the only admin. I have never deleted the group as my phone was not working well with the data I had to update the software.  So I transferred all related to my google account and saved with google drive.  Now I want to see all msg I had on this group and my then fiance and now husband (one person) that's all.

Comment: Use the email option mentioned in the answer below, to have the history of chats. There is no way to fully restore your messages. As mentioned below

Comment: Phone number recycling is the worst thing since social security numbers. Everytime I get a new phone number I inherit tons of debt collectors or ex-girlfriends I never wanted to hear from.

Answer (score 0):

In order to restore your messages from Google drive, you would need access to the same number that was used with WhatsApp during the backup.

From WhatsApp's [FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000019/?category=5245251#requirements)

> In order to successfully restore a Google Drive backup, you need to
>   use the same phone number and Google account used to create the back
>   up.

You can always ask the people that you chatted with, to send you a copy of the conversation by email, with the feature that WhatsApp providers for that [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/23756533/?category=5245251)

Depending on how desperate you are, you can call the number that you used to use with WhatsApp, and ask the person to help you restore the chats. The person would have to send you the verification number that he receives from WhatsApp, and after you successfully set up and restore your chats, you can change your number back to the new number that you have now. (Good luck with that)